# ng serve opens editor instead of loading local URL

Tags: command-line

Whenever I type `ng serve` or `ng serve --open`, it always opens an editor and doesn't open the project.

You can see this in the images below, this is the first image of command:

[image]

This editor opens after typing the command and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

[image: This editor opens after typing the command and pressing enter]

Comment: Can you add the output of `type ng` please? [Edit] your question and add it as plain, code-formatted text, not as screenshot.

Comment: @ByteCommander i just type ng serve in an angular 5 project. There is not output a blank editor file opens

Comment: Please try again in a separate, new terminal window and without navigating to your angular project directory. `type` should be a shell builtin, if that doesn't work, you did something weird because you're not running a Bash shell then.

Comment: @ByteCommander its also opening same editor.. What can be the issue?

Comment: @ByteCommander I suspect the OP has misunderstood `type ng` to be an instruction to "type" the command `ng`- rather than to "type `type ng`"

Answer (score 61):

This is the terminal editor on the 'ng' alias.
Uninstall it with:

```
sudo apt purge ng-common ng-latin
```

And then install Angular CLI (assuming you have npm installed) with

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

If you don't have npm installed [have a look here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993975/how-can-i-install-npm-on-17-10)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you installed your node with nvm, then put this in your .bashrc:

```
alias ang=~/.nvm/versions/node/`nvm current`/bin/ng
```

Or if your ng command is somewhere else, adjust accordingly. Then use angular with "ang" instead, and use the editor with "ng".

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers suggest, you execute ng (editor) (see [`man ng`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/man1/ng.1.html)) instead of the Angular CLI.

To locate the binary that is actually executed you can use:

```
$ which ng
/usr/bin/ng
```

There are a number of ways to work around the problem. Some are:

- Execute `npm start` instead of `ng serve`
- Modify the `PATH` environment variable (in your `.bashrc`). E.g. `export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH` if [npm's default directory was changed](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally#manually-change-npms-default-directory)
- [Use an alias](https://askubuntu.com/a/1263809)

PS: To exit the editor the shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> work for me.