# How can I install npm on 17.10?

Tags: apt, 17.10, npm, electron

I just wanted to install npm via terminal and now I am just stuck with some dependencies.

It wants me to install a few dependencies, for example:

```
libssl1.0-dev
nodejs-dev
node-gyp
```

Even if I try to install these first, it tells me I need the predecessor before.

Last instance of dependency is `libssl-dev` and this seems already installed.

Target is to install npm for making this [electron fork](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start) run on my system.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: @karel means i have no chance to install it on 17.10 and i am forced to downgrade to 16.04 again?

Comment: bro, i just wanted to know how to install npm on my system.
I cant just simple use "sudo apt install npm" because of the problem i have wrote in my first comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note: This answer has been updated since when it was first posted because there is now a better way of installing the latest version of npm which is built-in with the node snap package for installing Node.js. After running the below commands running `npm -v` will show that the latest version of npm is installed and being used.

---

Node.js is available as a snap package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. Specific to Node.js, developers can choose from one or more of the currently supported releases and get regular automatic updates directly from NodeSource. Node.js versions 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 and 18 are currently available, with the Snap Store being updated within hours or minutes of a Node.js release.

Node can be installed with a single command, for example:

```
sudo snap install node --classic --channel 11/stable # also install snapd in 14.04
```

The node snap can be accessed by the command `node`, for example:

```
$ node -v  
v11.5.0
```

An up-to-date version of npm will installed as part of the node snap. npm should be run outside of the node repl, in your normal shell. After installing the node snap run the following command to enable npm update checking:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /home/your-username/.config
```

Replace  **`your-username`** in the above command with your own username. Then run `npm -v` to check if the version of npm is up-to-date. As an example I checked that npm was up-to-date, checked the version of an already installed package named yarn with the command `npm list yarn` and then updated the existing yarn package to the latest version with the command `npm update yarn`

Users can switch between versions of Node.js at any time without needing to involve additional tools like nvm (Node Version Manager), for example:

```
sudo snap refresh node --channel=10/stable
```

Users can test bleeding-edge versions of Node.js that can be installed from the latest edge channel by switching with:

```
sudo snap switch node --edge
```

This approach is only recommended for those users who are willing to participate in testing and bug reporting upstream.

#### Node.js LTS schedule

| Release | Status | Codename | Initial release | LTS Start | Maintenance Start | Maintenance End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6.x | EOL | Boron | 2016-04-26 | 2016-10-18 | 2018-04-30 | 2019-04-30 |
| 7.x | EOL |  | 2017-05-30 |  |  | 2017-06-30 |
| 8.x | EOL | Carbon | 2016-10-25 | 2017-10-31 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-12-31 |
| 9.x | EOL |  | 2017-10-01 |  |  | 2018-06-30 |
| 10.x | EOL | Dubnium | 2018-04-24 | 2018-10-30 | 2020-05-19 | 2021-04-30 |
| 11.x | EOL |  | 2018-10-23 |  |  | 2019-06-01 |
| 12.x | Maintenance LTS | Erbium | 2019-04-23 | 2019-10-21 | 2020-11-301 | 2022-04-30 |
| 13.x | EOL |  | 2019-10-22 |  |  | 2020-06-01 |
| 14.x | Maintenance LTS | Fermium | 2020-04-21 | 2020-10-27 | 2021-10-30 | 2023-04-30 |
| 16.x | Active LTS | Gallium | 2021-04-20 | 2021-10-26 | 2022-10-18 | 2024-04-30 |
| 17.x | Current |  | 2021-10-19 |  | 2022-04-01 | 2022-06-01 |
| 18.x | Current |  | 2022-04-19 | 2022-10-25 | 2023-10-18 | 2025-04-30 |

Comment: Didn't work for me

Comment: Snap packages are terrible for SSDs. They are frequently updated causing heavy read/write actions on the disk, which is not optimal for the life of the SSD. I avoid them as much as possible. There's also the issue of security with Snaps, so just be careful.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. libssl is troublesome since lots of packages want different versions of it. The top troublemakers for me are Spotify, Viber, DotNet Core, php5.6 (legacy system).

Anyway, this solution seems to have worked:

Based on the answer by Jonathan Leaders, if you look at the script that it's downloading, you'll see it mention 2 key points: the repository, and the key.

For some reason after running just those commands, nodejs was still referring to the one in the official Ubuntu repositories, and it was an old version, with conflicting requirements for libssl.

Add them manually for reliable results (as root):

```
echo 'deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_9.x artful main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
curl -s https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key | apt-key add -
```

After that, simply `apt-get update` and then `apt-get install nodejs`

After that you'll have npm as well without installing anything additionally.

Note that this installs Nodejs 9.0, but I'm sure that the same method works for other versions as well. You just have to switch the version number in the repository source in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list`

Answer (score 1):

First see what version number is latest here:
 https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/tree/master/deb

In our case it is `setup_9.x`

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties curl
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Prove it is now installed

`npm -v`

Source: https://tecadmin.net/install-latest-nodejs-npm-on-ubuntu/

*Edit*: Added 'curl' to initial dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

### n-install

Node and npm installed with one line of `bash`.

[Installation of n](https://github.com/mklememt/n-install), the Node.js version manager, on Unix-like platforms, without needing to install Node.js first.
Additionally, installs scripts n-update for later on-demand updating of `n`, and `n-uninstall` for uninstalling.

The simplest case is installation of n with confirmation prompt, with subsequent installation of the latest LTS Node.js version:

```
curl -L https://git.io/n-install | bash
```

This is by far the simplest way to get started with both n and Node.js - even if you're looking to install only the latest LTS (long-term support) Node.js version, with no (immediate) plans to install multiple versions. The best part is that you can update the node version on the fly. It's got to be my favorite node tool. NVM is similar, but `n` is my preference.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use NVM. Which is a Node Version Manager that allows switching beetween diferent Node versions in a very simple way.
Just run the following commands:

`curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.8/install.sh | bash`

`command -v nvm`

Then, reopen your terminal and execute:

`nvm install lts/*`

That will download Nodejs source code and make installation for you.

Also, one of the key benefits of NVM, is the ability to install global packages without using `sudo`

If you want more information about NVM, check their Github Repo:

https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Comment: If the Node.js snap package is installed it is possible to switch between different versions of Node.js without needing to involve additional tools like nvm.

Comment: This is a great question. I don't believe you can since the core principal of snaps is to have the latest version of the software, which is isolated from the rest of the filesystem.