# Unable to install npm in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nodejs, npm

I have installed nodejs

```
$ nodejs -v 
4.2.6
```

now i am trying to install npm
i tried

```
sudo apt install aptitude

sudo aptitude install npm
```

it is showing

```
/usr/local/bin/node: 1: /usr/local/bin/node: cannot create 8��@P_�@@$@@@@@��@@@@�"��"� �"��"�'���
                                                    H&�H&'H&'00@@DDP�td �� �� ��ttQ�td/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2GNUGNU
                 eØGcP?ֺ����x��)Ě��@�: Directory nonexistent
/usr/local/bin/node: 1: /usr/local/bin/node: ELF: not found
/usr/local/bin/node: 2: /usr/local/bin/node: 3�
                                               : not found
/usr/local/bin/node: 3: /usr/local/bin/node: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
```

How to install npm

Comment: Tried all but not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install npm on 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993975/how-can-i-install-npm-on-17-10)