# install npm (node have been installed, npm missed)

Tags: apt, software-installation, dependencies, nodejs, npm

Ubuntu version is `18.04.1 LTS`

I need to upgrade node version. So following some forum recommendations I've uninstalled npm and node:

```
sudo npm uninstall npm -g
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove nodejs
```

install latest version of node:

```
curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_11.x | bash -
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nodejs
```

checking results:

```
> node --version
v11.6.0
> npm -v
bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory
```

trying to fix:

```
sudo apt-get install npm
```

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 npm : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-abbrev (>= 1.0.4) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ansi (>= 0.3.0-2) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ansi-color-table but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-archy but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-block-stream but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-fstream (>= 0.1.22) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-fstream-ignore but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-github-url-from-git but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-glob (>= 3.1.21) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-graceful-fs (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-inherits but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ini (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-lockfile but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-lru-cache (>= 2.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-minimatch (>= 0.2.11) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-mkdirp (>= 0.3.3) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-nopt (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-npmlog but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-once but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-osenv but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-read but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-read-package-json (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-request (>= 2.25.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-retry but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-rimraf (>= 2.2.2) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-semver (>= 2.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-sha but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-slide but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-tar (>= 0.1.18) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-underscore but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-which but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

### Question

Is any ideas, how to fix broken packages and install `npm` of latest version?

### More details:

following [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages).

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
```

prints nothing.

```
> sudo aptitude -f install node
env: ‘aptitude’: No such file or directory
```

different answers have not helped me.

Comment: @karel So... which package is broken? `node`, `npm` or different one?

Comment: To be honest if you install the node snap package you get all this: 1. npm is installed along with it 2. the **latest version** 3. your choice of all or any of the multiple versions of the node snap package 4. snap packages are standalone, so there are no possible problems due to broken packages - [How can I install npm on 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993975/)

Comment: @karel. I have no idea, how the links can help me fix my issue. following this links (with incomplete answers) issues and questions increases only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not managed my issues with broken packages (it seems hard to detect ones, but hoping somebody knows answer). But I've managed issue with `node` and `npm`.

To install node i've used article how to manage `node`s with [`nvm`](https://tecadmin.net/install-nodejs-with-nvm/).

install `nvm`:

```
> curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | bash
> source ~/.bashrc # to reload env
```

check accessibe versions for install:

```
> nvm ls-remote # to find latest stable version
> nvm install v11.6.0 # install node
```

and now I've installed:

```
> node -v
v11.6.0
> npm -v
6.5.0-next.0
```

`Npm` can be updated following their [instruction](https://docs.npmjs.com/):

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

Comment: Yes, Node Version Manager (nvm) is the final solution worked for me, reference https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-22-04#option-3-installing-node-using-the-node-version-manager