# ng serve opens editor instead of serving app, how to exit it

Tags: command-line

Related to [ng serve opens editor instead of loading local URL](https://askubuntu.com/questions/980708/ng-serve-opens-editor-instead-of-loading-local-url)

---

I tried to serve an app with `ng serve`, the prompt output:

```
Command 'ng' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install ng-common
```

But this is a text editor, not the angular cli. So now I see myself stuck on an editor harder than `vi` to exit

How do I quit this? `Crtl+C`, `ESC+Z+Z` or `\q` doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To **quit**, just press:

```
[Ctrl] + x
[Ctrl] + c
```

You will be asked if you wnat to save the file, just say `no` and confirm `yes`